# MoPub ads in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, ads, mopub

I want to add Mopub native ads in my unity project.
Is it possible to do it ? or can I just use native ads in Android or iOS native applications ? is there any way around to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried mopub's unity pluggin? It's open source and free.
http://www.mopub.com/2013/01/18/the-mopub-unity-plug-in-is-now-open-source/

There are 2 pluggins, one to use on android build and another to use with iOS.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried that plugin but I wanted to add native ads in my project. There are 3 types of ads supported by mopub i.e. banner ads,interstitial ads and another is native ads.So i want to use native ads.The link you have provided it helps to add only banner and interstitial ads not native ads.So,is there any way to add native ads into unity project ?